# multiple module loads from /etc/modules without device disconnect

Tags: kernel, usb, modprobe

I am flashing a device which enumerates with different product Ids during the flash process. When connected usbserial is correctly added based on my entry in /etc/modules. Once I flash the device, the device automatically re-enumerates but doesn't add usbserial again for the newly reported productId.

I am assuming it is because I didn't physically disconnect the usb device. If I do disconnect the device the initial image I flashed is lost and a I'm back a step one. Is there any way to get this to work without writing a custom kernel module?

Answer (score 1):

`usbserial` doesn't allow for multiple product IDs, so a custom kernel module is required.

Comment: Could you recommend such a kernel module?